# Pressing SUPER+L once locks screen but leaves side bar (dock) and desktop visible

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

Pressing <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> second time hides desktop but leaves side bar visible, not very safe situation.

Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Hmmm problem disappeared when i rebooted my laptop. I'm using multiple displays and dock if that could have anything to do with it.

Comment: also have this bug with two displays